# Plotting hundreds of markers onto a MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I can plot overlay markers on a map easily, but the requirements for this project ask for the addition of several hundred overlay markers. Obviously this causes ANRs all over the place.

I cannot use an AsyncTask to handle the addition of the overlay markers as the task cannot access the views.

So how can I move the addition of these overlays to the MapView in such a way that the app does not ANR?

Or is the realistic limit to the number of overlay markers I can plot much more limited?

Comment: Also consider clustering in maps if you are plotting thousands of markers.

Comment: Hey Ollie, how you done with it? I am having 200 pins to plot on Map. Please share a solution/idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `onPostExecute` and `onProgressUpdate` methods of the AsyncTask to hop onto the UI thread. You can manipulate your UI from within there. Remember to keep all the grunt work in the `doInBackground` method.

Trying to fire off a few hundred AsyncTasks is not a good idea so I recommend using a queue that a fixed number of AsyncTasks consume requests off.

Your next problem is dealing with performance when the user manipulates the map.

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting. I have hundreds of items to add, are you suggesting I add them in onPostExecute or onProgressUpdate? I moved my code to the former, and the app ANRs just as before. Are you suggesting I break up the addition of overlay markers into blocks, and do some in each progress update? I am only using one AsyncTask to add all of them - I am not firing off one for each (not least because I gather there's a fairly low limit to concurrent AsyncTasks anyway)

Comment: Updating the UI should be a fairly light process - so this should not involve anything to do with your data retrieval process. Yes, if you wish to do all the work in one AsyncTask, use `publishProgress` to update the UI in batches.